# How can I disallow Firefox configuration on a shared computer?

Tags: firefox

I want to disable:

- installing extensions
- changing toolbar/menu layout (the best would be to disable right-click on them)

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: It's possible, and you can even have the settings downloaded from a remote server; although right now I cannot remember any resources (might post an answer later). "Firefox lockdown" is a good keyword.

Answer (score 1):

The [Mozillazine article on Locking Preferences](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Locking_preferences) describes how to lock down copies of Firefox:

1. Pick the settings you want to lock
2. Create a lock file (e.g. `lockdown.cfg`) and add the Preferences you want to lock:

   > lockPref("some.preference.here", 0);
   >   lockPref("some.other.preference", 1);
   >   etc...

   You can also change the default preferences inside your file.
3. Load the lockfile:

   > "Create a new file (eg "local-settings.js") in the defaults/pref subfolder of the installation directory ..  and add the following line to the bottom, which points to the newly created lock file."
   >
   > pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);
   >   pref("general.config.filename", "lockdown.cfg");
4. Save and restart Firefox